# "efi: requested map not found error" terminated my Ubuntu installation on my Win8/Android tablet

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, uefi, live-usb, tablet

I have been attempting to install Ubuntu on my Android/Win8 tablet. I don't know it's brand, a pirated one.I followed the instructions by [Sturmflut](https://sturmflut.github.io/linux/ubuntu/2015/02/04/installing-ubuntu-on-baytrail-tablets-version-2/),[JOHN WELLS](http://www.jfwhome.com/2014/03/07/perfect-ubuntu-or-other-linux-on-the-asus-transformer-book-t100/) and jmithmstr.

I read many posts about how to install Ubuntu on x86_64 tablet.And There are many pioneers who succeeded in installing Ubuntu on it.But I get some troubles during installation process.

My tablet is different from the devices metioned on those articles. It uses 64 bit UEFI. I executed bootia32.efi in UEFI shell and errors appeared, so I don't need to add bootia32.efi into the `/EFI/BOOT/` directory.

Up to now, everything goes fine. I get into the BIOS and turn off **Quiet Mode**. After that, I select **UEFI:KINGSTONDT 101 G2 1.00** (My bootable option under **Boot Override**) .Then I run into a grub menu with options.

I click *Try Ubuntu without installing* and after a few minutes of black screen, I see a loading screen. It gets stuck on the loading screen for a while

(during this period, I pressed <kbd>Esc</kbd> and some information shows):

```
**(It seems that some I/O error encountered)**
```

A few minutes more at loading screen, some errors/info displays:

```
 [0.000000]efi: requested map no found
 [0.000000]esrt: ESRT header is not in the memory map.
 [0.125516]Ignoring BGRT: invalid status 0 (excepted 1)
 [36.856522]i8042: No controller found
 [37.251411][drm:intel_parse_bios [i9151] *ERROR* undefined sequence

 BusyBox v1.22.1(Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15-ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
 Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
 (initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system.
```

At the same time, the status indicator lamp of my live usb isn't on. Are there some problems on usb driver in kernel?

What can I try now?